# How to print a backslash (\) at the beginning of a string (c#)

Tags: c#, string, backslash

I have got the string:

```
string test = "\test.xml";
```

how can I print it out as: \test.xml

Comment: string test = "\\test.xml";

Comment: Just a quick remark: the only reason you were able to compile this code at all is that "\t" is escape sequence for a tab.

Comment: Who downvoted this? You don't have to google everything you know! What's wrong with asking simple questions on SO?

Comment: @Alex Asking requires another one to spend time to answer, searching for it first only requires yours. I would call it a common courtesy to search first. If you hover over the downvote button you see when you should downvote a question: "This question doesn't show any research effort; ...". Asking simple questions is fine, asking them without thinking first isn't in my opinion.

Comment: @Dirk I guess. At least OP accepted an answer :) That's a good thing.

Comment: when I typed "How to print a backslash (\) at the beginning of a string (c#)" I did not find an answer under: "Questions that may already have your answer" so I asked it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\` is an *[escape sequence character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)*.

```
Escape Sequence -- Represents

             \\ -- Backslash
```

If you want to use it in your string, you should escape it with another `\` character.

```
string test = "\\test.xml";
```

or your can use *[verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)* with `@` character like;

```
string test = @"\test.xml";
```

Comment: +1 I prefer the @"..." personally because it makes the text a lot more readable and gets rid of all the ugly escapes.

Comment: @Alex: it also allows to leave a multi-line string as it is which is handy especially for sql queries.

Comment: Yes, actually `'\t'` is _one_ character, a [TAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters). Each of `'e'`, `'s'`, `'t'`, `'.'`, `'x'`, `'m'`, `'l'` is also one character, so the string from the question had length `8`, not `9`.

Answer (score 4):

Just add escape sequence as:

```
string test = "\\test.xml";
```

Better option is to prepend '@' to avoid all escape sequences from string as:

```
string test = @"\test.xml";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string test = @"\test.xml";
```

or

```
string test = "\\test.xml";
```

Comment: The ``\\`` in your answer was escaped as well, by the Stack Overflow software ... (I need to edit this comment as well.)

Comment: Somehow late, isn't it?